# Can non-reduced fibers appear over a subset of codimension $\geq 2$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $f: X \to Y$ is a proper morphism of complex manifolds such that all fibers of $f$ are connected and of constant dimension $n = \dim X - \dim Y$. Also suppose that $Z \subset Y$ is an analytic subset of codimension $\operatorname{codim}(Z, Y) \geq 2$, such that $f$ is smooth over $f^{-1}(Y \setminus Z)$.

**Question:** Is it true that $f$ has reduced fibers?

Comment: Fibers of holomorphic maps between complex manifolds are always reduced, no? Because the ideal sheaf $I_x$ of $x\in Y$ is given by functions vanishing at $x$, i.e. is the full ideal sheaf. And the ideal sheaf of the fiber over $x$ is $f^{-1}I_x\cdot \mathcal{O}_X$ which again is the full ideal sheaf of functions vanishing on the fiber over $x$. More concretely, there exist $\text{dim}(Y)$ many local holomorphic functions $g_i$ on $Y$ with zero set $x$ and $g_i\circ f$ are holomorphic functions with the fiber as a zero set.

Comment: @t312t That's not correct. Non-reduced fibers of morphisms are one of the reasons why we consider nilpotent elements. For example consider the morphism $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C, z \mapsto z^n$. The set-theoretic fiber of $0$ is just $\{0\}$, but its ideal sheaf at $0$ in $\mathbb C\{z\}$ is generated by $z^n$, and hence the ideal sheaf is not a radical ideal.